Can Zero-Knowledge proofs leak information that does not break simulatability?
I currently do not understand the definition of Zero-Knowledge proofs.
When one initially starts reading about ZKPs, one learns that "no additional knowledge should be transmitted" other than the information x that we want to prove (e.g. that the prover has the secret, in an identification scheme). That makes a lot of sense.
However, the actual proofs seem to always simply show the existence of a simulator algorithm that can produce valid-looking transcripts and say that zero-knowledgeness follows from that. Now, I do understand the idea that the transcripts themselves can not convey information if a simulator that does not have any information can produce them.
My problem is that, the way I see it, we have two cases here:

Someone is simply given valid looking transcripts to look at. Yes, here we can indeed argue with the simulator to say that no information can be gained.
An honest but curious verifier actively participates in a protocol execution.

Now in case 2., we know that there already is at least one information that the verifier can gain (which he cannot gain in case 1.), namely the information x that we want to prove. The reason for this is that the verifier does not simply see a valid transcript, he has more information: For the example of a typical 3-step identification scheme, he knows that commit, challenge, and response were not chosen out-of-order (which is one of the techniques used by simulators to produce valid transcripts without knowing the secret). It is because of this extra information, on top of the valid transcript, that the verifier can be convinced of statement x.
This leads to my question: How do we prove that no other information is gained in case 2., i.e. during an actual protocol run? Simulatability I believe only covers case 1; it does not seem to account for the verifier's additional knowledge in case 2.
Clearly, I thought, I must be misunderstanding something here, so I looked up the original definition of the zero-knowledge property in the paper by Goldwasser et al., but it turns out they literally define it by existence of a simulator (section 3.3).
This obviously clears up why simulatability implies zero-knowledgeness (by definition), but the question remains if the so-defined zero-knowledgeness actually implies that zero additional knowledge is leaked to the verifier.
To give an absurd example, assume for a moment that the Schnorr identification scheme leaks the secret key s. Would this make a simulated transcript distinguishable from a real one for the verifier? I think it would not! A simulated transcript still looks (and technically IS) just as valid as a real one. The only difference being whether it was calculated in-order or not; an information that a distinguisher is not given.
Now in practice we know that the Schnorr scheme cannot leak s as long as the DLP problem is hard, but the fact that this doesn't seem to follow from simulatability is what grates me.
So, am I severely misunderstanding something here? Is there some clear argument for why any information gained in case 2. must either be the desired information x or has to break simulatability? Or can additional knowledge be gained, but we know that it is useless for all practical purposes (this would have to depend on the scheme then)? Is it maybe possible to apply Shannon's information theory to this whole issue?
Please enlighten me :)

The definition of zero-knowledge is that a for every possible verifier, there exists a simulator (without the witness) should be able to produce a simulated transcript from the viewpoint of this arbitrary malicious verifier. That is, the malicious verifier interacts with a player (however they want) which is either a honest prover with a witness, or a simulator without the witness. Zero-knowledge says that no verifier can possibly distinguish between these situations with non-negligible advantage.
The definition of Goldwasser et al. does provide this property. One way to understand that is that we consider a model of non-uniform adversaries, that could have arbitrary information hard-coded in their circuit. Hence, if the simulator produces a simulated interaction with a malicious verifier $V^*$ that is indistinguishable from the prover interaction for any polysize circuit, it is in particular indistinguishable from the viewpoint of $V^*$ itself, or that of any algorithm that would have arbitrary information hardcoded (the random tape of $V^*$, or even a witness, etc).
Note that in other writeups, the simulator is sometimes defined without talking about arbitrary $V^*$. This is typically the case when we consider public coin protocols and honest verifier. When we assume that the verifier is honest, and the protocol is public coin, the simulator can simulate an entire valid interaction in it's head and output that. However, this only provides a weaker notion, that of honest-verifier zero-knowledge. One motivation for studying HVZK is that we know generic and very efficient methods that turn any public-coin HVZK proof system into a full-fledged ZK proof system.

To give an absurd example, assume for a moment that the Schnorr identification scheme leaks the secret key s. Would this make a simulated transcript distinguishable from a real one for the verifier? I think it would not! A simulated transcript still looks (and technically IS) just as valid as a real one.

What simulator do you have in mind? If the identification leaks $s$, how could the simulator possibly simulate it, since it does not know $s$ in the first place? Remember: you have to describe an efficient simulator that only sees the statement and produces an indistinguishable transcript. In your example, if you could do that, you would break discrete log. So clearly, this protocol is not zero-knowledge unless discrete log is easy. If discrete log is easy... Then it's actually zero-knowledge! (but in an uninteresting and vacuous sense: if any one can compute the witness of a statement, then any proof of the statement hides "all informations that cannot be already computed from the statement").

Your very last point is what I was missing: The zero-knowledgeness property in combination with the hardness of e.g. DLP means that no information that reduces the entropy of the secret can be learned (it does not matter if the attacker is uncertain about whether or not the transcript was generated in-order, he could still use any information that reduced the key space). The information that the prover must know the secret doesn't reduce the entropy of the secret, so it can be learned without contradicting this (but here we care about certainty, so it can only be learned during execution).
